# how to resolve Google Bigquery custom quota for QueryUsagePerUserPerDay error, actually I already set quota unlimited?

Tags: google-bigquery

firstly, I already set my quota on bigquery requests per day and query usage per day be unlimited.
[image]
secondly, on my dashboard, I not see any quota that be exceeded.
[image]

but when I run python bigquery script that using service account, meet error as below:
*google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Custom quota exceeded: Your usage exceeded the custom quota for QueryUsagePerUserPerDay, which is set by your administrator*

how to resolve this error?

btw, I not the admin user.